# Creating a label which disappears after a few seconds

Tags: powershell

I am trying to achieve the following

1. User clicks a button
2. Label1 appears at the top left (text = "Hi there")
3. Label1 disappears after 5 seconds

I have tried to work with the timer function but the Interval setting just appears to work as it states, in intervals.

I don't want to use the Start-Sleep option because I need the form to still be active while this prompt appears.

```bsh
$timerPrompt = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Timer
$timerPrompt.Interval = 3000
$timerPrompt.Add_Tick({$form.Controls.Remove($label1)})
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be the full code section. Do you have a `$timerPrompt.Start()` and a `$timerPrompt.Stop();$timerPrompt.Dispose()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Drew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5552766/drew) already pointed out, your code does not show where you start, stop or dispose of the timer object.

This very simple form below creates a timer that gets started when the user clicks the button. In the `Tick` event of the timer it shuts itself down again.

Instead of removing the label, it hides and unhides it from view .

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
$form.Text = 'Test Timer'
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,200) 
$form.MinimumSize = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,150)
$form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

$label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,20) 
$label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(($form.Width - 20),50) 
$label.Text = "Hi There"
$label.Anchor = "Top","Left","Right"
$label.Visible = $false

$timer = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Timer
$timer.Interval = 5000
$timer.Add_Tick({ 
    # hide the label and stop the timer
    $label.Visible = $false 
    $timer.Stop()
})

$button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(($form.Width - 185),($form.Height - 80))
$button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$button.Anchor = "Bottom","Left","Right"
$button.Text = "&Click Me"
$button.Add_Click({
    # show the label and start the timer
   $label.Visible = $true
   $timer.Start()
})

# add the controls to the form
$form.Controls.Add($label)
$form.Controls.Add($button)
[void]$form.ShowDialog()


# when done, clean up the objects
$timer.Stop()
$timer.Dispose()
$form.Dispose()
```

Hope that explains

Comment: Thank you. I had my $timerPrompt.Stop() outside of the add_click function which seemed to cause the majority of my issues. Seeing your code made a lot of sense!

Answer (score 0):

I am not very good with GUI programming but I have a trick that will solve that problem for you as I have used it many of my GUI programs.

```
for ($i = 0; $i -lt 25; $i++)
{
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 200
    [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents()
}
```

Be advised that this is not ideal but I can't argue with the results. The little loop will give you a delay of 5 seconds while the `DoEvents()` part will keep ur form from going non responsive. Basically it checks for interrupts every 200ms giving the impression that the form is active.

Make the loop count 50 and reduce time to 100ms if you like. same results but extra responsiveness.